# Wildfly error WAR deployment error

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I get the following error when trying to deploy my war file

```
{
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {
        "jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./dmp" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./dmp: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'portcall.Actor' doesn't exist"
    }
}
```

Could anyone please advise on what the issue is?

P.S he war is supposed to create the DB structure on it own , the DB already exists with sufficient privileges.

Regards 
 Nick

Comment: What properties do you have defined in your `persistence.xml` file?

Comment: Sometimes you need to read the full error message : "Table 'portcall.Actor' doesn't exist"

Comment: The table is supposed to be created by the WAR file .

Comment: @ James 
In persistence.xml there is a datasource defined portcallDS , when I try to define it manually I get the following error . I am looking at it , any assistance is appreciated , Thank you !
Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:/MySqlDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]",
        "org.wildfly.data-source.portcallDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]"
    ]},
    "rolled-back" => true

Comment: @NicholasEvm ... any solutions for the above? I am also facing the same issue and not able to find solution